# Запрос на удаление по нескольким колонкам в одной таблице

Tags: postgresql

Помогите, мне надо удалить родителя и все его дочерние элементы.

Почему он не хочет удалять:

```
delete from comments where comment_id = 14 and parent_id = 14
```

Что я делаю не так?

То есть надо удалить родителя с `id` = 14 и все его дочерние элементы у которых поле `parent_id` = 14

Comment: Вы написали `where comment_id = 14 and parent_id = 14`. То есть Вы затребовали действие с ОДНОЙ записью, у которой оба поля равны 14 ОДНОВРЕМЕННО. Ясен пень такой нет. Замените `AND` на `OR`.

Comment: @Akina Я пробовал так, но выдает ошибку `ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 5: ...lete from comments where comment_id = 164 OR parent_id = 164
                                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: 1) DDL таблицы 2) Точный текст запроса 3) Цитату сообщения об ошибке с указанием, какое программное средство её формирует 4) Результат выполнения того же запроса через консольного клиента.

Comment: Я разобрался, привел к типу `integer` и все разаботало, спасибо

Comment: *привел к типу integer* O_O у Вас что, референсное поле имеет тип, не соответствующий реферальному? Небось и FK нету, руками целостность обеспечиваете? исправляйте это срочно, пока не стало поздно...